# how to reset progress wheel by using thread in android?

Tags: android, multithreading

i am using two progress wheel. in that, after completing the progress, how can i reset the first progress wheel and start the second one ?
my code:

```
        final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            running = true;

            while(progress<361) {
                pw_two.incrementProgress();
                progress++;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
                progress = 0;

            while(progress<361) {
                pw_one.incrementProgress();
                progress++;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
                progress = 0;

            running = false;

        }
    };
```

it get reset by clicking the button. but i need to reset after completion of the thread.

```
Button increment = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_increment);
increment.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
 public void onClick(View v) {
 if(!running) {
       pw_two.resetCount();
   pw_one.resetCount();
   Thread s = new Thread(r);
   s.start();

  }
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code.. am also using custom progresswheel..

```
if(pw_one.progress == 360) {  //  progress is valariable from Progresswheel class
pw_one.resetCount();
// then start the next one  
}

note : https://github.com/Todd-Davies/ProgressWheel
i just use this above link code..
```

Comment: thanks hari. i used this, but the application stopped unexpectedly after a few click made. and how can i start the next progress wheel?

Comment: this code is correct.one thing, you want to start the next wheel, when first wheel complete its progress ?

Comment: yes i want to start the next wheel, when first wheel complete its progress